# Google Map Fails to Load

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I tested this code on a test page but now want to implement it on a page that is called by an overlay (Lightview). The map is not displaying and I do not know why. The overlay spaces the size of a map, but nothing shows. Here is the code:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">    </script>
<?php
require_once('../maps/google.php');

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$zipcode = $_REQUEST['zipcode'];
$lookupPerformed = false;

if (strlen($zipcode) > 0) {
    $geocoder = new Geocoder('mykey');


    try {
        $placemarks = $geocoder->lookup($zipcode);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $lookupPerformed = true;
}
foreach ($placemarks as $placemark) {

$lat = $placemark->getPoint()->getLatitude();
$long = $placemark->getPoint()->getLongitude();
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  A Company: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat;?>, <?php echo $long;?>),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("../testxml.php?zipcode=<?php echo $zipcode;?>", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>
///// other PHP code

 </head>

        <form method="POST"  id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="submitAjaxFormDemonstration()">
        <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="zipcode" tabindex="1" value=" <?php echo $_POST['zipcode'];?>" /> 
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" name="submit" tabindex="2" />
        </form>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a pile of things going wrong here, and somethings which I can't even see to tell you whether they are right or wrong...

At the bottom of the posted code, you have:

```
 </head>

        <form method="POST"  id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="submitAjaxFormDemonstration()">
        <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="zipcode" tabindex="1" value=" <?php echo $_POST['zipcode'];?>" /> 
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" name="submit" tabindex="2" />
        </form>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You have a `<form>...</form>` element declared **outside** of the `<body>...</body>` tags - this is not valid HTML.

```
</head>

<body onload="load()">

<form method="POST"  id="ajaxForm" onsubmit="submitAjaxFormDemonstration()">
  <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="zipcode" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $_POST['zipcode'];?>" /> 
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Search" name="submit" tabindex="2" />
</form>

<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Fixes that... But you should probably use something like the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your HTML code. Bad HTML will almost always break Javascript (like Google Maps).

Next, you are invoking a PHP script which you do not explain at all `require_once('../maps/google.php');`. What is it? Where did you get it? Have you consulted their Tutorials or Documentation?

You are only showing us part of the problem here. You need to go back to Square 1 and check each step as you move forwards. Jumping to the end (which, from the looks of your code, is what you've tried to do) means that one of the hundred steps between Square 1 and there may have broken, and now you have to go back and look for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesnt fix anything. ../maps/google.php is the geocoder. I echod the lat and long and both are working. I understand that the form was outside the body tags, but makes no difference to the map not displaying. Will someone with google maps or prototype experience reply?

Comment: I do have Google Maps experience, thanks. Are you able to display a simple/standard map, without using the Geocoder? If so, the Geocoder (wherever you got it from) is the problem. If you can't see the map either way, then it is a problem with your HTML. You can't just dump your code here, only showing part of it, and expect people to find the problem.